# Expanding dynamically a table when hiding/showing a <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, expand

I'm currently developping a web application using Javascript via Aria Templates framework and I would like to dynamically expand/reduce a table when hidding/showing elements of my page (better would be without JS if it's possible).

Here is a little schema to explain myself better :

[Web page schema]

[image]

If the user hides the container 3, Table 2 should display rows (already loaded) in this new empty space. 
My question is : Is it possible to do this using only css/html properties or should I implement it using JS ?

I should add that the **height of table is calculated from the left space between Container 1 et container 3**

Adding some code as asked (won't be interpreted since it's Aria templates code) :

Aria Templates - HTML code :

```
<!-- Container 1-->
<div class = "widget_searchContainer" id = "widget_searchContainerId">
    <!--Some fields here -->
</div>

<!-- Table 2 -->
<!-- //Div displays header -->
<div class="header_background"> </div>  
<div class="innerTable"  id ="tableContainer"  style="height:${setTableHeight()}">  
    <div class="table-container">
                <table class="table">
        <thead style="max-width:100%;"> 
            <tr class="tableHeaderCells" id="tableHeader">

            <!-- Aria Templates for and code -->
            {foreach column in columns}
                <th  style="width:${column.width}; overflow:hidden">
                    <div class="th-inner">
                        <span>${column.name}</span>
                        <span class="sortIcons">
                            <!-- //{call filter("owner")/} -->
                            <!-- //{call sort("owner")/} -->
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </th>
            {/foreach}  

            </tr>
        </thead>
        {foreach row in rows}   
            <tr class = "highlightOnHover {if evenRow == 0}evenRow{else/}oddRow{/if} " style = "max-width:100%">
            {var rowValueIndex = 0 /}
            <!-- //displays each cell of the row -->
            {foreach value in rowValues}
                <td class="centeredCell" style="width:${columns[rowValueIndex].width}; overflow:hidden"> ${value} </td>
                {set rowValueIndex = rowValueIndex + 1 /}
            {/foreach}
        {/foreach}
        </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
</div>          

<!-- Container 3 -->
<div class="widget_hierarchyContainer" id = "widget_hierarchyContainerId">          

    <! -- //Allows to show/hide hierarchyContainer -->
    <div class="toRightBottom" style="margin-bottom:1em; margin-right:2em;">
        myButton
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css file associated :

```
    /* Container 1 */
div.widget_searchContainer {
        background : ${c_grey4};
        position: relative;
        border : 1px solid blue;
        width : auto;
}
/* Table */
.table-container {
        padding-top: 30px;
        position: relative;
        width:100%;
    }

    .header_background{
        background: ${c_amadeus_blue};
        text-align: center;
            height: 30px;
            left: 0;
                position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
    }

    .innerTable{
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        width : 100%;
    }

    .th-inner {
            line-height: 30px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            top: 0;
    }
    .table {
        table-layout : fixed;
        border-collapse : separate;
        width : 100%;
    }

    /* Container 3*/
    div.widget_hierarchyContainer {
        background : ${c_grey4};
        border : 1px solid blue;
        width : 100%;
        position : absolute;
        bottom : 0px;
        height : 100px;
        overflow : auto;
    }
```

Comment: can you upload your code to jsfiddle ?

Comment: maybe switching Table 2 to CSS-display:none / display: block(e.g.) might do it

Comment: As mentioned, code would be nice. Can section 2 be a scrolling div with fixed height?

Comment: Heights of Container 1 et Container 3 are fixed and height of table is calculated from their heights and page height